# collapse multiple rows of a dataframe into single row based on unique id in r

Tags: r, database, excel

I have a data set with millions of rows. The first row has an ID, though there are repeated IDs in the data set (all IDs are grouped and ordered). The data set has multiple columns. I would like to transform the data such that there is one row item per ID, and all the previous entries of the columns for the ID are put into a single row, in order.

See example snippet of the before data

[image: What the data currently looks like]

And example of what I would like the data to look like
[image: What the entries should look like]

Here is an example of a very similar problem, however in this problem the data only has two columns (one column for the ID), but my data has over 5 columns (and one column for ID): [Collapse mutiple rows of a dataframe into one row - based on a unique key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28123814/collapse-mutiple-rows-of-a-dataframe-into-one-row-based-on-a-unique-key)

I would like to do this in either R or Excel :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `R`, we can do this with `dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), ID ~ rowid(ID), value.var = c("V1", "V2"), fill = "")
#   ID V1_1 V1_2 V1_3 V2_1 V2_2 V2_3
#1:  1    a    b    c   aa   bb   cc
#2:  2    d    e        dd   ee     
#3:  3    f             ff
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3), V1 = c("a", "b", "c", 
 "d", "e", "f"), V2 = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff")), .Names = c("ID", 
"V1", "V2"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked very well. However, when I tried to run it again the very next day with the same code (I'd saved the code the night before), I got an error which said:Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds
In addition: Warning message:
In if (!(value.var %in% names(data))) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: @user5211911  Can you try it based on the data on by post

Comment: Yes, it does so even when I use the data from your post. I copy pasted the data from your post into R but it did not work and gave me the same error. Though this is strange, as it worked the first time I tried it but now it doesn't work

Comment: Okay I just turned my computer on and off again and the code worked now...quite strange